# Want to use ASM for fast 8 byte aligned array copy instead of memmove

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I've got an array of structs that are sized to be within an 8 byte boundary. I need to move the data around in big chunks within the array itself, so I've been using memmove(). It works, but it's very slow. I think the compiler is not optimizing the function to copy 4 or 8 bytes at at time, hence the delay.

What I would rather do is force the copy by using int32_t or int64_t vars. That way, I can have the memcpy copy 4 or 8 bytes at at time, speeding things up. This will work ok since my structs are always sized to 8 byte boundaries.

I can't figure out a way to force this in C. I tried to do it with inline assembly, but I don't know how to point the operands to specific array elements. For example, if my ASM statement copies 4 bytes at a time, I need to advance the array by 4 bytes. I don't know how to do that. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
//here's our 2048 byte struct
typedef struct {
    filename[1024];
    description[1024];
} RECORD;

//total number of rows, or elements
int row_count = 0;

//create initial record
RECORD *record = (RECORD*)malloc(sizeof(RECORD));

//insert some stuff
strcpy(record->filename,"filename.txt");
strcpy(record->description,"Description of file");

//increment our row count
row_count++;

//now let's add a row
record = (RECORD*)realloc(record,sizeof(RECORD)*(row_count+1));

//duplicate first record
//copy first 4 bytes from "record" to the newly appended row
//obviously this would be a loop copying 4 bytes at a time
//up to the the size of the row, which is 2048 bytes.
__asm__("movl (%1), %%eax; \n\t"
    "movl %%eax, (%0); \n\t"
    : "=r"(record+row_count)    //output
    :  "r"(record+0)            //input
    : "%eax" );                 //list of registers used

//Don't work. :-(
```

Comment: What platform and compiler are you on?

Comment: `memcpy`/`memmove` is a highly optimized procedure in the runtimes shipped with current major compilers, you shouldn't try to outperform it. (And yes, it doesn't move single bytes.) Perhaps you should better optimize your algorithm so that it doesn't need copying large amounts of data?

Comment: Do the areas you move your data from/to overlap? If not, did you try with memcpy?

Comment: I don't know why you think memmove will be implemented poorly. Did you look?

Comment: Are you sure your performance problems aren't related to poor memory access locality?

Comment: You don't need memcpy/memmove, you're copying structures so simply `record[row_count]=record[0]` would do (and let the compiler work out how to do that).

Comment: Also, if you realloc every time you add a record, there is a chance that memmove (or something similar) is being called internally by realloc **for every record** you add, resulting in O(N*N) behaviour.

Comment: Your next move is to profile the code to work out what is the true performance bottleneck. At the moment it looks exceedingly likely that you don't know what that is. Your strategy of reimplementing memmove is liable to lead to your program running even slower.

Comment: Thanks, I was approaching things wrong. Stupid mistake. I indeed had a loop that was running realloc on every iteration. That was the source of the bottleneck. I removed the loop and it's working perfectly now. Thank you!

Comment: It might be worth trying this as an exercise, but even getting close to the performance of your system's `memmove` should be counted a victory.

Answer (score 4):

As @Vlad pointed out, `memmove` & `memcpy` are generally highly optimized, these days they are generally implemented with SIMD for big blocks, this means you should really profile your code before spending time optimizing what you *think* to be the bottlenecks.

On to your actual question:
you don't have any looping in your copy, however, its better to use something such as `REP MOVSD` for 4-bytes at a time or `REP MOVSQ` on x64 for 8-bytes at a time. however, seeing your data is 8 byte aligned, you can even use MMX to do copies, via [MOVQ](http://www.tommesani.com/MMXDataTransfer.html), which would do 64bits at a time.

This becomes a little more complex when there is overlapping and other funny corner cases, but from the sounds of it you shouldn't have/need that, so in fact, the best approach might be the most naive one (this just copies, which will speed up things if you don't need the other semantics of `memmove`):

```
void MyMemCopy(void* pSrc, void* pDst, int nElements)
{
    int64_t* s = (int64_t*)pSrc;
    int64_t* d = (int64_t*)pDst;
    while(nElements--)
        *d++ = *s++;
}
```

now the compiler if free to optimize this in the best way possible, be it inlining or unrolling etc, and you don't have the portability issues of ASM